# how to get point set (x,y) in a desired area in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

[image]

The figure is the plot of x,y set in a excel file, total 8760 pair of x and y. I want to remove the noise data pair in red circle area and output a new excel file with remain data pair. How could I do it in R?

Comment: Hand-drawn red circles are not an adequate criteria of what constitutes "noise". Clarifying your question is an important step towards answering it. What do you mean by "noise"? Also, please refrain from asking too many questions at once. Removing noise (however defined) from a set of points and communicating with Excel are two very different problems.

Comment: By the way, for simple data, you can just use csv files as a go-between for R and Excel. There are R packages which can read from and write to Excel and Excel add-ins which can link to R, but that might be overkill for something like this.

Comment: I would try quantile regression with a spline predictor, which would enable you to omit points above the predicted 90th percentile (or whatever).  Can we have a reproducible example please?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to clarify my question clearly next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @G5W's example:

Make up data:

```
set.seed(2017)
x = runif(8760, 0,16)
y = c(abs(rnorm(8000, 0, 1)), runif(760,0,8)) 
XY = data.frame(x,y)
```

Fit a quantile regression to the 90th percentile:

```
library(quantreg)
library(splines)
qq <- rq(y~ns(x,20),tau=0.9,data=XY)
```

Compute and draw the predicted curve:

```
xvec <- seq(0,16,length.out=101)
pp <- predict(qq,newdata=data.frame(x=xvec))
plot(y~x,data=XY)
lines(xvec,pp,col=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Keep only points below the predicted line:

```
XY2 <- subset(XY,y<predict(qq,newdata=data.frame(x)))

plot(y~x,data=XY2)
lines(xvec,pp,col=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

You can make the line less wiggly by lowering the number of knots, e.g. `y~ns(x,10)`

Comment: A Nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Both R and EXCEL read and write .csv files, so you can use those to transfer the data back and forth.

You do not provide any data so I made some junk data to produce a similar problem.

DATA

```
set.seed(2017)
x = runif(8760, 0,16)
y = c(abs(rnorm(8000, 0, 1)), runif(760,0,8)) 
XY = data.frame(x,y)
```

One way to identify noise points is by looking at the distance to the nearest neighbors.  In dense areas, nearest neighbors will be closer. In non-dense areas, they will be further apart.  The package `dbscan` provides a nice function to get the distance to the k nearest neighbors. For this problem, I used k=6, but you may need to tune for your data. Looking at the distribution of distances to the 6th nearest neighbor we see that most points have 6 neighbors within a distance of 0.2

```
XY6 = kNNdist(XY, 6)
plot(density(XY6[,6]))
```

[image: Density Plot]

So I will assume that point whose 6th nearest neighbor is further away are noise points. Just changing the color to see which points are affected, we get

```
TYPE = rep(1,8760)
TYPE[XY6[,6] > 0.2] = 2
plot(XY, col=TYPE)
```

[image: Noise turned red]

Of course, if you wish to restrict to the non-noise points, you can use

```
NonNoise = XY[XY6[,6] > 0.2,]
```